# Можно ли сделать repeat для тега img?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы изображение в теге `img` повторялось(repeat) по горизонтали. **Нужно именно чтобы в теге `img` повторялось**, а не `background-image`.

Answer (score 2):

Непосредственно картинку в теге img повторять нельзя. Только `background-image`. Можно с помощью JS брать ссылку на картинку и ее через `background` повторять. Примерно выглядеть это будет так:

```
var $el = document.getElementById( 'rightflower' )
  , $img = $el.getElementsByTagName( 'img' )[0]
  , src  = $img.src

$el.innerHTML = "";
$el.style.background = "url( " + src + " ) repeat-y;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Я понял из вопроса, что URI картинки хочется только в html использовать.
Можно ведь инлайн-стилем указать background элемента.

```
<div class="inline_bg_image" style="background: url('some url') repeat-y;" />
```

А остальные свойства стиля для этого элемента поместить в css файле